# Number Operations and Return Types

Tags: swift

I am confused by what is returned when performing number operations in Swift between various types. Consider the following:

```
var castedFoo = Float(7.0/5.0) // returns 1.39999997...

var specifiedTypeFoo:Float = 7/5.0 //returns 1.39999997...

var foo = (7/5.0) //returns 1.4
```

What separates the first two from the last one? They are all returning floats, so why is the value from the last one rounded? I understand that the first is casted and the second explicitly specified to be a Float, but the last one also returns a Float value. So what makes the difference here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [Swift documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/LexicalStructure.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH30-XID_879),

> Unless otherwise specified, the default type of a floating-point literal is the Swift standard library type Double, which represents a 64-bit floating-point number.

In other words, the literal `5.0` is of type `Double`.

Your first two examples set the result type to `Float`; your last example keeps the type of the result a `Double`, because the result of the division of an `Int` and a `Double` is a `Double`. Because of that difference, the last result has higher precision.

Comment: I see! But why is there a loss of precision when casting? Thanks!

Comment: @Blakeasd `1.4`'s representation as a floating-point number is not precise. Its binary mantissa looks like this: `1 .011(0011)` with `0011` repeated as many times as you can fit in a particular representation (32 bit, 64 bit, and so on). When the number is printed out, the small representation error is enough to produce the `1.39999997` with `Float`. With `Double` it has more nines after the dot, so it gets printed as `1.4`.

Comment: In other words the loss of precision is because a 64 bit `Double` is more precise than 32 bit `Float`.

Comment: This may help with a deeper understanding: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21895756/why-are-floating-point-numbers-inaccurate

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Ok, that makes sense now. I just had to read more about how floating point numbers work in binary to understand your response. Thank You Again!